# Is it possible to airblast needles in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-pyro

I know that you can airblast arrows from the sniper and any projectiles. I believe needles are projectiles, but I have never seen or tried to ariblast needles. Does it work?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. They're just like bullets.

From http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Compression_blast:

> The following projectiles can be compression blasted:
>
> - Rockets (Sentry Rockets, Energy Blasts, and Eyeballs)
> - Grenades and cannonballs
> - Stickybombs
> - Baseballs and ornaments
> - Flares
> - All liquid based projectiles.
> - Arrows, healing bolts, and repair claws.
> - Cleavers

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience, no, they are treated as bullets.